# Fetching data from previous record in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, ireport

How do I write a mongodb query in *iReport* to fetch data from previous record?
Example,  
I have 3 columns - start,end,rest.
'Rest' has to be calculated as the difference between start of one record and the end of previous record. ('start' and 'end' are dates)

Comment: You can't access the values from the previous record in *JasperReports*. In some cases the *JasperReports* variables can help you

Comment: See Lucianc (Lucian Chirita) answer [http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/517853/how-calculate-relative-percentages-wrt-recor](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/517853/how-calculate-relative-percentages-wrt-recor)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. Basically you have to rework the data in the query so that it has the right format when it is about to be printed in JasperReport. This can be accomplished with runCommand command or mapreduce command given that you have sufficient permissions. Your best option is probably mapreduce. I suppose you have read this [reference](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jaspersoft-mongodb-query-language).